# Json objects in dataframe to list in R

Tags: r, json

I have the following in a csv file, I would like to convert into list..

```
{"received":1589294883,"guid":"0CA2F400004","eventtype":"basic","payload":{"time":1589294882,"commodity":"elec","updatetime":1589294882,"total":{"units":"kWh","cons":1625591},"status":{"disconnect":false}}}
{"received":1589294888,"guid":"0CA2F400004","eventtype":"basic","payload":{"time":1589294887,"commodity":"elec","updatetime":1589294887,"total":{"units":"kWh","cons":3769124},"status":{"disconnect":false}}}
{"received":1589294892,"guid":"0CA2F400004","eventtype":"basic","payload":{"time":1589294889,"commodity":"elec","updatetime":1589294889,"total":{"units":"kWh","cons":949678},"status":{"disconnect":false}}} 
{"received":1589294898,"guid":"0CA2F400004","eventtype":"basic","payload":{"time":1589294897,"commodity":"elec","updatetime":1589294897,"total":{"units":"kWh","cons":5137203},"status":{"disconnect":false}}}
{"received":1589294902,"guid":"0CA2F400004","eventtype":"basic","payload":{"time":1589294900,"commodity":"elec","updatetime":1589294900,"total":{"units":"kWh","cons":968410},"status":{"disconnect":false}}}
```

someone managed to do this, but didn't show how. if I can get this to the right format then I can then structure it using:

```
library(jsonify)
jsonify::from_json( json_file )
jsonlite::fromJSON( json_file )
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be quite slow, but you could give it a try:

```
do.call(rbind,lapply(readLines("example.csv"),function(x)data.frame(jsonlite::fromJSON(x))))
```

or even:

```
jsonlite::fromJSON(paste0("[",paste0(readLines("ex.csv"),collapse = ","),"]"))

    received        guid eventtype payload.time payload.commodity payload.updatetime payload.total.units payload.total.cons payload.disconnect
1 1589294883 0CA2F400004     basic   1589294882              elec         1589294882                 kWh            1625591              FALSE
2 1589294888 0CA2F400004     basic   1589294887              elec         1589294887                 kWh            3769124              FALSE
3 1589294892 0CA2F400004     basic   1589294889              elec         1589294889                 kWh             949678              FALSE
4 1589294898 0CA2F400004     basic   1589294897              elec         1589294897                 kWh            5137203              FALSE
5 1589294902 0CA2F400004     basic   1589294900              elec         1589294900                 kWh             968410              FALSE
```

If this is too slow, then you should consider making the whole file Json compatible. something like:

```
write(sprintf("[%s]",paste0(readLines("example.csv"),collapse=",")),"example1.csv")
```

then read it in with `json`:

```
jsonlite::fromJSON("example1.csv")
```

Comment: Thank you for your  answers, I am getting these errors with first and second methods respectively: Error: parse error: trailing garbage
                           "{""received"":1589001247,""guid"":""0CA2F4
                     (right here) ------^ Error: parse error: after array element, I expect ',' or ']'
                          ["{""received"":1589001247,""guid"":""0CA2F4
                     (right here) ------^                       so it is extra double quotes! Thank you

Comment: one more thing about the way the file is saved, it is not comma delimited, each json object is on a new line!

Comment: @DAL, so you mean you have extra doule quotes? You just said yu have a `comma delimited file`. Read your question again

Comment: @DAL, does this code work in the example you provided?

Comment: I know it is confusing, the file extension is .csv , I copied those lines after importing the file with read.csv() i.e. single column dataframe. I used your code on the file .csv directly then the error (double quote) problem came up. Did you save my example above as .csv first? thanks again.

Comment: @DAL so how did you import the csv file into R? to produce the above values?? Also, you should not say the csv file contains ... because that is not what the csv file contain but rather that is what you see in R after READING your csv. So What does csv file contain? How did you read it into R?.

Comment: @DAL, take a note that the answer provided solves the question ASKED and not the QUESTION INTENDED. no one is able to perceive what you intend. If you need people to answer your question, you should consider this as answered and then ask a different question. Editting this wont be enough since people only respond to new questions, no one scrolls down to page three or four to solve the questions there

Comment: I know you have solved it, I just don't know how you did it. the lines I provided is what I can see in R , by using read.csv().

Comment: @DAL. do not use read.csv. But allow me ask if you read.csv(...,sep="\t")[1,] what do you get?

Comment: 2  {"received":1589001247,"guid":"0CA2F400004","eventtype":"basic","payload":{"time":1589001246,"commodity":"elec","updatetime":1589001246,"total":{"units":"kWh","cons":500073},"status":{"disconnect":false}}}
3 {"received":1589001251,"guid":"0CA2F400004","eventtype":"basic","payload":{"time":1589001250,"commodity":"elec","updatetime":1589001250,"total":{"units":"kWh","cons":1582882},"status":{"disconnect":false}}}

Comment: @DAL is there any difference between what you have and what you previously had?

Comment: No, I think they are identical

Comment: when you run `data.frame(jsonlite::fromJSON(readLines("your_file.csv")[1]))` what do you get?

Comment: Error: parse error: trailing garbage
                                 "x" "{""received"":1589001247,""guid"
                (right here) ------^  pointing to the double quote..

Comment: "\"{\"\"received\"\":1589001247,\"\"guid\"\":\"\"0CA2F400004F68EF\"\",\"\"eventtype\"\":\"\"basic\"\",\"\"payload\"\":{\"\"time\"\":1589001246,\"\"commodity\"\":\"\"elec\"\",\"\"updatetime\"\":1589001246,\"\"total\"\":{\"\"units\"\":\"\"kWh\"\",\"\"cons\"\":500073},\"\"status\"\":{\"\"disconnect\"\":false}}}\""

Comment: okay. now can you run `data.frame(jsonlite::fromJSON(gsub("\"+","\"",readLines("your_file.csv"))[1]))`

Comment: Error: parse error: trailing garbage
                                    "{"received":1589001247,"guid":"0C
                     (right here) ------^ pointing to 'recieved'..

Comment: @DAL can you open your csv file, copy the first line and paste it here? Because when you have already read in the data things change. How does the first file in your csv look like?

Comment: {"received":1589001247,"guid":"0CA2F400004F68EF","eventtype":"basic","payload":{"time":1589001246,"commodity":"elec","updatetime":1589001246,"total":{"units":"kWh","cons":500073},"status":{"disconnect":false}}}

Comment: @DAL consider asking a new question, with the data AS IT LOOKS IN THE CSV not the already read in data. Feel free to come back here and tag me to the question

Comment: so each cell in the first column contains one of those lines. I hope this helps and thank you for your patience.

Comment: @DAL One need to know the structure of your data in the csv file and not when read. or paste the results of `dput(read_in_data)` so that one can have the exact replication of what you have. Please ask a new question with the rectified data. Otherwise you might end up not solving this. I am sorry I am unable to reproduce your error. Thats why cannot help. Ask a new question and feel free to tag me. once The data is rectified, i will be able to note what is the issue

Comment: I will,Thank you very much, you have been great help.